# Fibonacci and golden ratio

Tags: fibonacci-numbers, golden-ratio

I'm reading a book about algorithms and there is some explanation of Fibonacci numbers. So it says that

$$ F_i = \frac{\phi^i - \hat{\phi^i}}{\sqrt{5}}, $$
where $\phi^i$ is golden ratio and $\hat{\phi^i}$ is its conjugate.

I understand that if $|\hat{\phi^i}| < 1$ then $\frac{|\hat{\phi^i}|}{\sqrt{5}} < \frac{1}{2}$. Then the author says that the previous inequality implies that
$$ \left\lfloor{\frac{\phi^i}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1}{2}} \right\rfloor. $$
So, my first quesiton is why the author is using '$+$' while in the first expression we have '$-$' ?

And the second question is related to the following author's conclusion about the last expression:

> which is to say that the ith Fibonacci number $F_i$ is equal to $\frac{\phi^i}{\sqrt{5}}$ rounded to the nearest integer.

Could someone please explain to me why the author ignores $\frac{1}{2}$ ?

Comment: Is this "book" you speak of, by any chance Introduction to Algorithms, by Cormen et.al?

Comment: Yes, this is Introduction to Algorithms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$ *is* rounding to the nearest integer. $\lfloor x\rfloor$ truncates the decimal expansion of $x$, so in order to get the nearest integer instead of always getting the one below it, you have to add $1/2$.

Comment: Oh, I got it. The nearest integer is not the same as a result of the floor function. Thank you very much for good explanation. By the way, have you had a chance to look at my first question? I still don't understand why the author change the sign in the formula. Why he is adding $\frac{1}{2}$ while in the formula we have $\frac{\phi^i - \hat{\phi^i}}{\sqrt{5}}$ ? Just to get the nearest integer? If so, it's a bit strange for me..

Comment: Think of the "rounding function" $r(x) = \lfloor x+1/2\rfloor$. The author is saying $F_i = r(\phi^i/\sqrt{5})$. The $1/2$ has nothing to do with the explicit formula--it's just part of the rounding operation.

Comment: Ok, then what I'm worrying about is why is he ignoring the second part of the first expression and to get a Fibonacci number using only the first part of it? And why is he saying that this one $\frac{|\hat{\phi^i}|}{\sqrt{5}} < \frac{1}{2}$ implies this one $ \left\lfloor{\frac{\phi^i}{\sqrt{5}} + \frac{1}{2}} \right\rfloor. $? I'm sorry for my stupidity, just want to completely understand it.

Comment: $|\hat{\phi}|<1$, so as you raise it to higher powers, it gets closer and closer to zero. Thus, rounding to the nearest integer on $\phi^i/\sqrt{5}$ always gets the right answer, because the correction term $\hat{\phi}^i/\sqrt{5}$ is always small.

Comment: Ok, I see. Thought something like this. Thank you very much for your help!